Sudo apt upgrade caused a migration to Ubuntu 24, which failed
I was on Ubuntu 22 LTS. I made a sudo apt upgrade, then noticed there was no more the button to power off in the upper right menu and so shut down violently (the applications were closed though)
When I turned the PC on again, I got only a Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS console, telling me Expanded security maintenance for application is not enabled. I created a token at Ubuntu site and ran pro attach $thattoken, but got Failed to connect to https://contracts.canonical.com/v1/magic-attach Temporary failure in name resolution
And now I don't know what to do and have to use my smartphone instead of my PC.

Does it work if you execute the commands in that answer? https://askubuntu.com/a/1525026/124466

Sorry, I posted a wrong link previously, which really should have nothing in common. Please try this new link

OK. Update it as described in that answer, and enter the commands after that one by one

I made a sudo apt upgrade, then noticed there was no more the button to power off -- In future, please always look at the output of apt before confirming it to proceed. The output must have given indications that it would alter many necessary packages

OK I may have been negligent. Reading your link, I've run sudo apt full-upgrade but it fails: a lot of "failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu/...

Are you connected to the internet? If not fresh installing ubuntu 24.04 would be a less painful procedure to fix

Yes, except that I lose some data (the most important one is in the cloud, but still, I was more trustful than that in Ubuntu). Trying to mail and copy to a USB drive from the command line, but nothing works for the moment

Working with a USB drive

Yes, except that I lose some data -- Not at all. Before reinstalling, you can "Try Ubuntu", and use that session to recover any data you want. When you reinstall, only the data in the root partition and home folder will be erased. Just copy all those data to a separate partition where Ubuntu will not be installed

Oh yes, that's right but it's done now. And does it still work when the hard drive is encrypted? (it is)

Sorry, I don't know anything about encrypted hard drives. Perhaps ask a new question about the data extraction before you perform a format

No, the problem is not solved, but bypassed

The users of this site are volunteers who help you with Ubuntu issues. We are not Ubuntu developers. We can't solve every problem, but at most help you find a workaround.

Yes, sure, I know, I was not complaining about you. Thanks for the help.
